# setParameter function of hibernate does not work

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to update a record on database, I am using the following code to do so,

```
System.out.print("Update");
Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query q = session1.createQuery("FROM Developer WHERE id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", 1);
Developer developer = (Developer)q.list().get(0);
developer.setContact("Jack");
session1.update(developer);
```

once I run the project it shows the following on console and does not go further.

```
INFO: Update
INFO: Hibernate: select developer0_.id as id0_, developer0_.contact as contact0_,   
   developer0_.phone_1 as phone3_0_
   from developer developer0_ where developer0_.id=?
```

**Developer.java**

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
/**
 *
 * @author Jack
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="developer")
public class Developer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8767337896773261247L;

    private int id;
    private String contact;
    private int phone_1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.id = ID;
    }

    @Column(name="contact")
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String Contact) {
        this.contact = Contact;
    }

    @Column(name="phone_1")
    public int getPhone_1() {
        return phone_1;
    }

    public void setPhone_1(int Phone_1) {
        this.phone_1 = Phone_1;
    }


}
```

I can use the following code to insert rows into same table on database

```
Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session1.beginTransaction();
session1.save(developer);
session1.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984579/why-does-setparameter-not-set-the-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you don't open the transaction in the update method? you should always use transaction.

```
Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();
 Query q = session1.createQuery("FROM Developer WHERE id = :id");
    q.setParameter("id", 1);
    Developer developer = (Developer)q.list().get(0);
    developer.setContact("Jack");
    session1.update(developer);
 session1.getTransaction().commit();
```

also why you don't use session.get to get object with its id instead of using query?
you may do it like this.

```
Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session1.beginTransaction();
        Developer developer = (Developer)session1.get(Developer.class,1);
        developer.setContact("Jack");
        session1.update(developer);
     session1.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: great I forgot to include transaction :D Ive tried to use session1 but when I type it auto complete shows there is no get method in it with only one parameter!!! my imports are as following import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import net.viralpatel.contact.model.Developer;
import net.viralpatel.contact.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Query;

Comment: @JackRamzi yes sorry i never memorize method signature, you've to add class type.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class, java.io.Serializable)